# Role of Akka in SMACK architecture

Tags: scala, akka, smack

What is the role of Akka in SMACK architecture when we already have Spark in it. SMACK is all about data processing which is provided by Spark then why do we need Akka at all there?

Answer (score 1):

Try to call spark jobs from your frontend web application. Good luck :)

if that doesn't work very well, then let Akka actors process data from your frontend web application.

Comment: So you are saying its only akka-http to invoke spark jobs. Phew!! how about spark jobserver or livy then?

Comment: I am saying that Akka is a great middleware which interacts very well with real time front-end applications. While Spark is a great backend data processing technology.

Comment: but how does akka and spark interact with each other in context of SMACK?